# ¿Cómo separar con coma números en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Tengo una tipo calculadora en que ingresas una cantidad y te va a dar el ahorro que vas a generar.

El problema que tengo es que quieren que esté la cantidad del ahorro separada por una coma cuando son cantidades grandes.

Estuve revisando la funcion split() pero veo que solo sirve en string.

En este input ingresas la cantidad que quieras:

```
 <input required id="valor" type="text" placeholder="$$" onkeyUp="calcular();">
```

En este span se genera la cantidad que se va a ahorrar:

```
  <span id="ahanul"></span>
```

Aquí mando llamar el valor del input y del span:

```
  var valor = document.getElementById("valor").value;
  var totalahrr = document.getElementById('totalahrr');
```

Y aquí hago la formula para los resultados:

```
  var ahorro = parseInt(totalant) - parseInt(totalds);
```

[Codigo](https://codepen.io/luis-uribe/pen/NWqKwpw)

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer uso del método [toLocaleString](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolocalestring_number.asp), es fácil de utilizar espero te funcione.

```js
var n = new Number(1000000);
var myObj = {
  style: "currency",
  currency: "MXN"
}

document.write(n.toLocaleString("es-MX", myObj));
```

Answer (score 0):

tambien puedes usar esta funcion

```
function currencyFormat(num) {
return '$' + num.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '$1,');}
```